# How to deal with cherry-pick error with Github?

Tags: git, husky

Trying to cherry-pick between 2 branches: dev & qa. I did `git cherry-pick <hash>` but it yield

```
/c/Program Files/nodejs/yarn: line 5: cygpath: command not found internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985 throw err; 
^ Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-2.9.11\resources\app\git\node_modules\yarn\bin\yarn.js' at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:15) at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:27) at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12) at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 { code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND', requireStack: [] } 
husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 1 (error)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the cherry-pick that fails, but your environment is missing something. The error message you get is quite descriptive, and should help you find out what is wrong.

When you figure it out, it would be nice if you could update your question with what went wrong, in case it's a common error others might encounter.

The error message says:

1. Your repo has a pre-commit hook (ie `.git/hooks/pre-commit`)
2. The hook ie either a 'yarn' script or relies on `yarn`
3. `yarn` is expecting to find some modules in its search path
4. The search path that `yarn` uses is incomplete or wrong or unset
5. The default location where `yarn` expects to find modules is `resources\app\git\node_modules\yarn` or similar under GitHub desktop's CWD, and the module is not there.

Check if all these expectations are correct, and you'll likely find one of them is not correct.

If you're part of a bigger team, whoever set up the repository should know how to make it useable with GitHub Desktop. The pre-commit script was added locally, and whoever owns it has your answer.